# Finding index of cells of underlying collection of gridview's datasource using LINQ

Tags: c#, winforms, linq, datagridview

I have a gridview which is binded using BindingList<>. I am trying to change some values to grid's cell. So, I extracted the list and trying to find the cell using the where conditon in linq  where i made change, but no success.

Graphically,it is

```
Col1    Days    col3    DateStart    DateEnd
----------------------------
1       14       3        12-12-2013  25-12-2013
5       4       3        06-03-2013  09-03-2013
```

**Update:**

In the above table, if i change the days, then end date will get increased by the no of days suuplied. That is , in row 2 my date is 6th march - 9th march which is 4 days difference{see days column it has 4}, if I change it to 6 then the new end date will 11-03-2013 (dd-mm-yyyy)

Comment: Does that make sense? _"So i want to know if I change 7 to 1 in row 2 then how to identify that row and column"_

Comment: Sorry, but what I want to say is that, if I made chane in col4 then i need to reflect some changes in the its respective row in some columns, so for that i need that item from list using linq from my collection